# How to search a package in Dandified YUM (DNF) using Regex?

Tags: linux, command-line, fedora, repository, dnf

I am not asking about workarounds, I am asking about **dnf** usage with **regex**. No greps or additional gadgets.

Comment: The man page for `dnf` is fairly specific. `?`, `*`, and `[` are allowed and follow shell glob matching. Regex is not mentioned in the man page.

Comment: `man dnf`, there's no need to be so passive-aggressive.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such feature in DNF as it stands.

However, as it is open source, and the code is here: https://github.com/rpm-software-management/dnf5. You could develop a regex search function. You may even get it accepted as an official feature.

This is *usually* a snarky way to answer, but given that you've asked for answers that don't use external tools... that's pretty much the only answer.